# R: Split observation values by and aggregate to time intervals

Tags: r, time, intervals

There are bird observations from various observation points (**obs**) over certain areas (**name**). The **start** and **end** time was taken, and the time difference (**diff_corr**) recalculated with a correction factor, so it is not simply `difftime` of the start-end-interval.

I now need to "split" these values to "nice" intervals (15 minutes,  e.g. 10:15:00, 10:30:00, ...) and then aggregate area-wise(**name**) in order be able to make a plot of the presence of birds on those areas in those clean 15-minute-intervals.

So, to make it a little more clear: An observation might start at 10:14 and goes till 10:25, so it spans over the interval 10:00-10:15 and 10:15-10:30, so the value I got should be split and assigned accordingly to the appropriate intervals by the part they have into that interval.

In a more complicated setting, an observation might span over 3 or 4 intervals, and so the value has to be split there accordingly as well.

The last step would be to aggregate all observation parts per interval and plot them.

I already searched for solutions for some days, but only found very simplistic examples where intervals were rearranged with `cut` and `breaks`, but never examples what to do with associated values, but simple frequency counts.

example data:

```
structure(list(obs = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"C2", "Dürnberg2"), class = "factor"), name = c("C2", "C2", 
"C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "b", "981", "1627", 
"b", "b", "981", "1627", "b", "b", "b", "b"), start = structure(c(1495441500, 
1495441590, 1495441650, 1495441680, 1495447380, 1495447410, 1495447530, 
1495447560, 1495447580, 1496996580, 1496996580, 1496996580, 1496996760, 
1496996820, 1496996820, 1496996820, 1496997180, 1496997300, 1496997420, 
1496998260), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1495441590, 
1495441650, 1495441680, 1495441800, 1495447410, 1495447530, 1495447560, 
1495447580, 1495447620, 1496996760, 1496996760, 1496996760, 1496996820, 
1496997180, 1496997180, 1496997180, 1496997300, 1496997420, 1496997540, 
1496998320), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), diff_corr = c(1.46739130434783, 
0.978260869565217, 0.489130434782609, 1.95652173913043, 0.489130434782609, 
1.95652173913043, 0.489130434782609, 0.326086956521739, 0.652173913043478, 
2.96703296703297, 2.96703296703297, 2.96703296703297, 0.989010989010989, 
5.93406593406593, 5.93406593406593, 5.93406593406593, 1.97802197802198, 
1.97802197802198, 1.97802197802198, 0.989010989010989)), .Names = c("obs", 
"name", "start", "end", "diff_corr"), row.names = c("1", "9", 
"7", "8", "3", "2", "4", "5", "6", "13", "13.1", "13.2", "22", 
"11", "11.1", "11.2", "12", "23", "15", "16"), class = "data.frame")
```

p.s. I have real difficulties to name my question properly, so any hints (not only on that) are highly appreciated

New attempt for a small example:
Assigning the value to intervals by their proportion (and later sum up equal intervals)

```
start         end         value     new values in new 15-min-intervals
10:03:00      10:14:00    11        ---> 10:00:00 =  11
10:14:00      10:16:00     2        ---> 10:00:00 = 1 ; 10:15:00 = 1
10:00:00      10:35:00    40        ---> 10:00:00 = 40/35*15 ; 10:15:00 = 40/35*15 ; 10:30:00 = 40/35*5
10:15:00      10:30:00    12        ---> 10:15:00 = 12
```

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, you want to get an average or cumulative sum of all `diff_corr` values? The other columns are strings so they can not be summed/averaged etc.

Comment: Do you mean reformat the time interval (diff_corr) column to 15 min time stamps?

Comment: @Gautam Yes, I need the sum of diff_corr, but for the "nice" interval of the quarters of an hours it's proportions are falling in.

Comment: @SaleemKhan diff_corr is not a time interval but the recalculated minutes of observation within the interval of start and end. Those should be split into proportional parts of the 15 min intervals within an hour and then summed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` approach which allows you to use SQL-type queries to sort/filter data and perform operations.

**DATA**

```
> p
    obs name               start                 end diff_corr
 1:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 04:25:00 2017-05-22 04:26:30 1.4673913
 2:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 04:26:30 2017-05-22 04:27:30 0.9782609
 3:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 04:27:30 2017-05-22 04:28:00 0.4891304
 4:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 04:28:00 2017-05-22 04:30:00 1.9565217
 5:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 06:03:00 2017-05-22 06:03:30 0.4891304
 6:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 06:03:30 2017-05-22 06:05:30 1.9565217
 7:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 06:05:30 2017-05-22 06:06:00 0.4891304
 8:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 06:06:00 2017-05-22 06:06:20 0.3260870
 9:  C2   C2 2017-05-22 06:06:20 2017-05-22 06:07:00 0.6521739
10:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:23:00 2017-06-09 04:26:00 2.9670330
11:   b  981 2017-06-09 04:23:00 2017-06-09 04:26:00 2.9670330
12:   b 1627 2017-06-09 04:23:00 2017-06-09 04:26:00 2.9670330
13:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:26:00 2017-06-09 04:27:00 0.9890110
14:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:27:00 2017-06-09 04:33:00 5.9340659
15:   b  981 2017-06-09 04:27:00 2017-06-09 04:33:00 5.9340659
16:   b 1627 2017-06-09 04:27:00 2017-06-09 04:33:00 5.9340659
17:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:33:00 2017-06-09 04:35:00 1.9780220
18:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:35:00 2017-06-09 04:37:00 1.9780220
19:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:37:00 2017-06-09 04:39:00 1.9780220
20:   b    b 2017-06-09 04:51:00 2017-06-09 04:52:00 0.9890110
```

**CODE**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
p <- as.data.table(p)
p[, .(new_diff = mean(diff_corr)), .(tme_start = round_date(start, unit = "15min"))]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> p[, .(new_diff = mean(diff_corr)), .(tme_start = round_date(start, unit = "15min"))]
             tme_start  new_diff
1: 2017-05-22 04:30:00 1.2228261
2: 2017-05-22 06:00:00 0.7826087
3: 2017-06-09 04:30:00 3.3626374
4: 2017-06-09 04:45:00 0.9890110
```

**What is Data.Table doing?**

Since you aren't familiar with `data.table`, here's a very quick, elementary description of what is happening. General form of the `data.table` call is:

```
DT[select rows, perform operations, group by]
```

Where `DT` is the `data.table` name. `Select rows` is a logical operation e.g. say you want only observations for C2 (name), the call would be `DT[name == "C2",]` There is no operation required to be performed and no grouping. If you want the sum of `diff_corr` column for all `name == "C2"`, the call becomes `DT[name == "C2", list(sum(diff_corr))]`. Instead of writing `list()` you can use `.()`. The output will now have a only one row and one column called `V1` which is the sum of all `diff_corr` when `name == "C2"`. The column doesn't have a lot of information so we assign it a name (can be the same as the old one): `DT[name == "C2", .(diff_corr_sum = sum(diff_corr))]`. Suppose you had another column called "mood" which reported the mood of the person making the observation and can assume three values ("happy", "sad", "sleepy"). You could "group by" the mood: `DT[name == "C2", .(diff_corr_new = sum(diff_corr)), by = .(mood)]`. The output would be three rows corresponding to each of the moods and one column `diff_corr_new`. To understand this better try playing around with a sample dataset like `mtcars`. Your sample data doesn't have enough complexity etc. to allow you to explore all of these functions.

**Back to the answer - other variations**

It's not clear from the question or comments if you want to round based on `start` or `end`. I used the former but you can change that. The example above uses `mean` but you can perform any other operations you may need. The other columns seem more or less redundant since they are strings and you can't do much with them. You could use them to further sort the results in the `by` entry (last field in the code). Below are two examples using `obs` and `name` respectively. You can also combine all of them together.

```
> p[, .(new_diff = mean(diff_corr)), .(tme_start = round_date(start, unit = "15min"), obs)]
             tme_start obs  new_diff
1: 2017-05-22 04:30:00  C2 1.2228261
2: 2017-05-22 06:00:00  C2 0.7826087
3: 2017-06-09 04:30:00   b 3.3626374
4: 2017-06-09 04:45:00   b 0.9890110


> p[, .(new_diff = mean(diff_corr)), .(tme_start = round_date(start, unit = "15min"), name)]
             tme_start name  new_diff
1: 2017-05-22 04:30:00   C2 1.2228261
2: 2017-05-22 06:00:00   C2 0.7826087
3: 2017-06-09 04:30:00    b 2.6373626
4: 2017-06-09 04:30:00  981 4.4505495
5: 2017-06-09 04:30:00 1627 4.4505495
6: 2017-06-09 04:45:00    b 0.9890110
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer so far. Had to do some more stuff and have real difficulties to understand what data.table is doing the with its , and . round_date etc. 1. I need the sum, not the mean, but this seams to work properly. 2. What I still have to find out if your solution really divides diff_corr, if the start-end interval crosses a 15min-break. Have to find examples. What I already found out is, when the end time falls exactly on a break, the value goes to a separate interval and not the lower one. Will need something if end <= break then... Ok, further investigating

Comment: Look up the `Data.table` package to learn more about querying. Here's a good resource:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html `Round_date` is a function from the `lubridate` package which does what the name suggests - round dates. It's useful when rounding for different intervals (7 min, 2 hours, 12 seconds etc.). You can easily replace `mean` with `sum` to get the sum. I'll add some more explanations to the code.

Comment: Boahhh, took me days to learn even the basics of data.table and your syntax is still a mystery to me ... but in combination with some additional fuddling, i seem to reach my goals ... a week after I was expected to deliver. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is slow and clunky, but maybe it's helpful. Calculates counts and weighted diff_corr sums by name and 15 minute interval:

```
library(dplyr)
range <- seq.POSIXt(min(df$start)-(15*60), max(df$end)+(15*60), by = "15 min")

df$totalDuration <- as.numeric(as.difftime(df$end-df$start),units=c("secs"))

out <- NULL
for (r in 1:length(range)){
  subset <- df %>% filter( (start >= (range[r]-(15*60)) & start<range[r]) |
                             (end>= (range[r]-(15*60)) & end<range[r] ) |
                             (end > range[r] & start < range[r])) %>%
    mutate(bin=range[r],
           duration = ifelse(start>=(range[r]-(15*60)) & end<range[r],totalDuration,
                        ifelse(start>=(range[r]-(15*60)),as.numeric(as.difftime(range[r]-start),units="secs"),
                          ifelse(end<range[r],
                                 as.numeric(as.difftime(end-(range[r]-(15*60))),units="secs"),
                                            as.numeric(as.difftime(range[r]-(range[r]-(15*60))),units="secs")
                        )))
           ) %>% 
    mutate (diff_corr_W = diff_corr*(duration/as.double(totalDuration, units='secs'))) %>%
    group_by(bin,name) %>% summarise(count=n(),
                                     diff_corr_sum = sum(diff_corr_W)) %>% ungroup()


  if (is.null(out)){
    out <- subset
  } else {
    out <- rbind(out,subset)
  }
}


> out
# A tibble: 9 x 4
bin  name count diff_corr_sum
*              <dttm> <chr> <int>         <dbl>
  1 2017-05-22 04:40:00    C2     4      4.891304
2 2017-05-22 06:10:00    C2     5      3.913043
3 2017-06-09 04:25:00  1627     1      1.978022
4 2017-06-09 04:25:00   981     1      1.978022
5 2017-06-09 04:25:00     b     1      1.978022
6 2017-06-09 04:40:00  1627     2      6.923077
7 2017-06-09 04:40:00   981     2      6.923077
8 2017-06-09 04:40:00     b     6     13.846154
9 2017-06-09 04:55:00     b     1      0.989011
```

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have failed in explaining it correctly. Examples for counting frequencies are availble already. But I need the values of diff_corr split and assigned in it's proportions of the quarters of an hour. But thanx for the example.

Comment: Edited above based on your comments.

Comment: Many thanx for your example. I will first try the other solution before I dare to dive into mutate-ifelse-groupby-whatever conglomerat ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree it ended up looking gross. The nested ifelse is to assign durations to the 15 minute intervals, but there's probably a cleaner logic to do that. 

It might also be clearer to remove the `group_by` so you can examine whether the duration and diff_corr are distributed correctly. Then do the `group_by` outside the loop.

Comment: Though you solution did not work out for me (could get it to work), especially the idea idea with the "range"-variable inspired me for other things. Thanx.